# VS Code Extension API: How can I display compressed navigation items in a treeview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview, vscode-extensions

I am using the [Tree View API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view) to display an object structure in my VS Code extension. In some situations, the path structure contains single deeply nested items so there is a lot of visual overhead by all the parent nodes. I would like to compress these chains of nodes similar to what we can see in the built-in explorer pane of VS Code:

[image]

How is this possible via an API? Am I expected to do the compression by myself and merge all nodes into a single `TreeItem`? Or is this compression functionality available via the Tree View API?

Comment: what happens if you just create directory nodes that only have 1 directory node and the last directory node has some entries

Comment: [@rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69134297/vs-code-extension-api-how-can-i-display-compressed-navigation-items-in-a-treevi?noredirect=1#comment122191370_69134297) Not sure what you mean. Even if the last directory node has zero entries, there is no folding applied like we can see it in the default explorer pane.

Comment: there is a setting that controls the folding to happen or not

Comment: also know that the GUI has more features than the extension API, you can always write a `WebviewView`

Comment: You are not referring to `collapsibleState`, are you? I don't this controls the folding shown in the screenshot above. / Webview appears to be overkill and the docs [disrecommend](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#should-i-use-a-webview) you use them if they add little value to the UI only.

Comment: I think he is referring to the setting: `Explorer: Compact Folders` but that probably won't affect your TreeView.